# Comparing two value using java

Tags: java

> I want to compare the score of score A AND score B and then I want the show the string "TEAM A IS WINNER" by comparing the values of both score and please also tell me how's the layout of this app because I am a newbie to android programming and this is the first app I working on.< [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZxwV.png >

```
package android.example.scorekeeper;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button b_ROLL;
    ImageView red_4;
    int score_A = 0;
    int score_B = 0;
    String winnerScore ;
    Random r;
    int rolledNumber;

    public void addOneForTeamA(View V) {
        score_A = score_A + 1;
        displayForTeamA(score_A);
    }

    public void addTwoForTeamA(View V) {
        score_A = score_A + 2;
        displayForTeamA(score_A);
    }

    public void addThreeForTeamA(View V) {
        score_A = score_A + 3;
        displayForTeamA(score_A);
    }

    public void addFourForTeamA(View V) {
        score_A = score_A + 4;
        displayForTeamA(score_A);
    }

    public void addFiveForTeamA(View V) {
        score_A = score_A + 5;
        displayForTeamA(score_A);
    }

    public void addSixForTeamA(View V) {
        score_A = score_A + 6;
        displayForTeamA(score_A);
    }

    public void addOneForTeamB(View V) {
        score_B = score_B + 1;
        displayForTeamB(score_B);
    }

    public void addTwoForTeamB(View V) {
        score_B = score_B + 2;
        displayForTeamB(score_B);
    }

    public void addThreeForTeamB(View V) {
        score_B = score_B + 3;
        displayForTeamB(score_B);
    }

    public void addFourForTeamB(View V) {
        score_B = score_B + 4;
        displayForTeamB(score_B);
    }

    public void addFiveForTeamB(View V) {
        score_B = score_B + 5;
        displayForTeamB(score_B);
    }

    public void addSixForTeamB(View V) {
        score_B = score_B + 6;
        displayForTeamB(score_B);
    }

    public void WinnerScore(View v) {
        if (score_B < score_A) {
            String winner = "Team A is Winner";
            System.out.println(winner);
        } else {
            String winner = "Team B is Winner";
            System.out.println(winner);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Displays the given score for Team A.
     */
    public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    /**
     * Displays the given score for Team B.
     */

    public void displayForTeamB(int score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.b_score);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    /**
     * Displays the winner from both teams.
     */

    public void displayForwinner(String score) {
        TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.winner);
        scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        b_ROLL = (Button) findViewById(R.id.id_roll_the_dice);
        red_4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_red_1);
        r = new Random();
        b_ROLL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rolledNumber = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
                if (rolledNumber == 1) {
                    red_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_1);
                } else if (rolledNumber == 2) {
                    red_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_2);
                } else if (rolledNumber == 3) {
                    red_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_3);
                } else if (rolledNumber == 4) {
                    red_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_4);
                } else if (rolledNumber == 5) {
                    red_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_5);
                } else if (rolledNumber == 6) {
                    red_4.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_6);
                }

            }
        });
        displayForTeamA(score_A);
        displayForTeamB(score_B);
        displayForwinner(winnerScore);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your code what have you done.

Comment: please share your code here which helps us to find the problem better and sooner

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @PoornaSenaniGamage i shared the code

Answer (score 0):

Your method `WinnerScore` is almost there, you are just missing the update to the display.  Create another `TextView` to display this message, and simply update the content with the message.  Note that capitalizing the first letter is usually reserved for class names, so you may want to get in the habit of lower-casing first letter of your method names.

On the side note, if you put `r = new Random()` in `OnCreate` it will only get called once.  Put it as the first line inside the `onClick` method.  That way if you click on the roll button, the randomization will happens all the time.  You also need to move or copy the `displayFor` methods inside and at the end of the `onClick` method so the score display gets updated accordingly.

Comment: and what about the screen layout is it looking great ?

Answer (score 0):

```
The answer will be 
public void WinnerScore(View v) {

        if (score_B > score_A) {
            Winner = "Team B is Winner";
            displayForResult(Winner);
        } else if (score_B < score_A) {
            Winner = "Team A is Winner";
            displayForResult(Winner);
        } else {
            Winner = "DRAW MATCH";
            displayForResult(Winner);
        }

    }
```